# Why the validates overrides old restrictions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, testing

I very new in Rails, but my problem I have is:

When I just the type the following code:

```
  validates :ipaddress, :format => {
    :with => Resolv::IPv4::Regex,
    :message => 'Deve ser um endereco IP valido'
  }
```

All my tests works with no problem. But when I add:

```
  validates :ipaddress, :format => {
    :with => Resolv::IPv4::Regex,
    :message => 'Deve ser um endereco IP valido'
  }

  validates :domain, :format => {
    :with => URI.regexp,
    :message => 'Deve ser um dominio valido'
  }
```

The tests starts to failure and say:

```
F

Failure:
UrlTest#test_test_url_with_valid_IP_address 
[/home/olegario/infracrawler/test/models/url_test.rb:7]:
Test a valid IP address.
Expected: true
Actual: false


bin/rails test test/models/url_test.rb:4

..F

Failure:
UrlTest#test_test_url_using_a_valid_domain [/home/olegario/infra-
crawler/test/models/url_test.rb:19]:
Test a valid domain.
Expected: true
Actual: false
```

Why this is happening?

**EDIT**

This is the code of my tests:

```
test 'test an url with a IP address containing characters' do
  url = Url.new()
  url.ipaddress = '192.168.2.AAA'
  assert_equal(false, url.valid?, 'Test a invalid IP address')
end

test 'test url using a valid domain' do
  url = Url.new()
  url.domain = 'http://google.com'
  assert_equal(true, url.valid?, 'Test a valid domain')
end
```

Comment: Because two `validates` clauses are “**each**,” not “**either**.” Please show the test itself.

Comment: You get errors precisely because new restrictions __do not__ override/cancel old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are validating Both `domain` and `IP` **Both of them not Either one.**

The first test for the ip address would fail and return false even if you provide a valid ip address.

I think the right tests should be as the following

```
test 'test an url with a IP address containing characters' do
  url = Url.new()
  url.ipaddress = '192.168.2.AAA'
  url.domain = 'http://google.com'
  assert_equal(false, url.valid?, 'Test a invalid IP address')
end

test 'test url using a valid domain' do
  url = Url.new()
  url.ipaddress = '192.168.2.1'
  url.domain = 'http://google.com'
  assert_equal(true, url.valid?, 'Test a valid domain')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your testing methodology and assumptions about validations are wrong. The `.valid?` method runs all of the validations in the model. The resulting errors are added to the errors hash in the model instance. If the errors hash is empty then it returns true (it is valid) otherwise false.

Therefore testing validations by asserting that `.valid?` is true/false is error prone since each test must take every other validation into consideration.

To test a single validation in isolation you should write assertions about the errors hash:

```
test 'test an url with a IP address containing characters' do
  url = Url.new(ipaddress: '192.168.2.AAA')
  url.valid? # runs the validations
  assert_true(url.errors.has_key?(:ipaddress))
  assert_contains(url.errors][:ipaddress], 'Deve ser um endereco IP valido')
end

test 'test an url with a valid ip' do
  url = Url.new(ipaddress: '192.168.2.1')
  url.valid? # runs the validations
  assert_false(url.errors.has_key?(:ipaddress))
end
```

Comment: Also I really don't see why you would create such a model in the first place when Ruby has a [URI module](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/URI.html) for this very purpose.